# Pedir un numero e indicar si se encuentra dentro de un array o no - JAVA

Tags: java

Estoy intentando hacer un programa donde el usuario escriba por teclado 6 números y los guarde en un array. Posteriormente pedir un número e indicar si este, se encuentra dentro del array:

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a,b,c,d,e,f,var; //VARIABLES ARRAY
        
        System.out.println("Introduce un número: ");
        a = s.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Introduce un número: ");
        b = s.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Introduce un número: ");
        c = s.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Introduce un número: ");
        d = s.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Introduce un número: ");
        e = s.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Introduce un número: ");
        f = s.nextInt();
                
        //Declaraciones arrays.
        int intArray[]; //declaramos como tipo int al array
        
        //Asignamos tamaÃ±o.
        intArray = new int[6]; //asignamos el tamaÃ±o del array [5]
        
        //Asignamos datos al array.
        intArray[0] = a;
        intArray[1] = b;
        intArray[2] = c;
        intArray[3] = d;
        intArray[4] = e;
        intArray[5] = f;
        
        //VARIABLES ELEMENTO 1 AL 6
        int i = a;
        int z = b;
        int x = c;
        int w = d;
        int y = e;
        int l = f;
        
        System.out.println("Pide un numero: ");
        var = s.nextInt();
        
        boolean v = true;
        
        while (v == false){
            if(var == i){
            System.out.println("Se encuentra dentro del array: " + intArray[0]);
            }
            
            if(var == z){
            System.out.println("Se encuentra dentro del array: " + intArray[1]);
            }
            
            if(var == x){
            System.out.println("Se encuentra dentro del array: " + intArray[2]);
            }
            
            if(var == w){
            System.out.println("Se encuentra dentro del array: " + intArray[3]);
            }
            
            if(var == y){
            System.out.println("Se encuentra dentro del array: " + intArray[4]);
            }
            if(var == l){
            System.out.println("Se encuentra dentro del array: " + intArray[5]);
            }
           
            while (v == true){
                if(var != i){
                    System.out.println("No se encuentra dentro del array");
                }  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El problema es que no logro hacer que si el número que ponga NO se encuentra dentro del array, lo diga.
Como podéis ver, al final de todo, intento hacer esto con un true o false, pero no se donde está el error.

El problema es que por ejemplo, al ejecutar el código, si el número no está en el array, no sale el print de "No se encuentra dentro del array"

Me estoy iniciando en JAVA.

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trabajar con arreglos evita tener que trabajar con variables separadas como `a,b,c,d,e,etc..`.

Agrego código usando ciclos para trabajar con el arreglo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        // variable que contiene la longitud del arreglo
        int longitudDelArray = 5;

        // crear nuevo arreglo con la longitud
        int[] intArray = new int[longitudDelArray];
        
        // pedir el ingreso doe los número y guardarlos dentro del arreglo
        for (int i = 0; i < longitudDelArray; i++) {
            System.out.println("Introduce un número: ");
            intArray[i] = s.nextInt();
        }

        // pedir el número a buscar
        System.out.println("Pide un numero: ");
        int n = s.nextInt();

        
        boolean existe = false;

        // recorrer el arreglo
        for (int i = 0; i < longitudDelArray; i++) {
            // si el arreglo contiene el número a buscar
            // poner la variable existe en true y terminar el ciclo
            if(intArray[i] == n) {
                existe = true; 
                break;
            }
        }
       // imprimir el resultado
        System.out.println("El numero " + (existe ? "existe" : "no existe"));



    }
```

Comment: Mersi! Me funcionó! =)